# google app script: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues')

Tags: google-apps-script

``I am trying to create PDFs from data submitted on google forms, but an error is throwing up as "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues')."
I have linked google forms and spreadsheet, also added triggers but still error is coming up.
And my second question is how I can put the images submitted by google forms in the pdf that is created by the code?

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF(info);
  deleteTemp();
}


function createPDF(info){

  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1L7PT2BmT6BF5CHuOhwIYO2fMONxlX3-gPnVTH0HwO6Q");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("183kQJO9hTKStqbLkjS0XE6Fo8P11AiwT");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1pfQS679sYw5Pos6QxfXRXj_VtvN0aOeQ");

  const newTempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{date}", new Date());
  body.replaceText("{name}", info['Full Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{gender}", info['Gender'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{age}", info['Age'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{number}", info['Mobile Number +91 -'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{email}", info['Email Id'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{addr1}", info['Street / Landmark / Village Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{addr2}", info['Block Name / Post Name / Town'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{city}", info['District / City'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{state}", info['State / UT'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{pin}", info['Pin Code'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{profession}", info['Profession'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{experience}", info['Work Experience'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{photo}", info['Upload your passport size photograph'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Full Name'][0]);

}

function deleteTemp() {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("183kQJO9hTKStqbLkjS0XE6Fo8P11AiwT")
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext()){
      files.next().setTrashed(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have chosen the wrong trigger.  There are two onformsubmit triggers.  One for a form and one for a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Cooper I have selected the event source as "from spreadsheet - on form submit" in the triggers. I think the issue is to retrieve data for the questions with multiple choice, checkbox and file upload options in the form, because after removing those fields the code is working fine.

Comment: Try something like this just to see what the keys look like: `function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  let info = e.namedValues;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(info).map(k => [k,info[k][0]])))
}`

Comment: @Cooper I tried the above function and it's giving me the expected Key value pairs. My Code was fine, maybe the problem was with the linking of form and the spreadsheet. I deleted the earlier work and started fresh, created a new spreadsheet and created a form from the spreadsheet, added the same script and triggers and now it is working fine.

Comment: @Cooper Images that are uploaded using the form are shown as links in the PDF that is created. How can I add them as images in the pdf and not as links?